# Magento 2.1: Price including/excluding tax

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, price

The price of my configurable product shows the price including tax like it's set in the backend. But next to it I want to display the price excluding tax. Is this possible? Because the block only holds Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice.

Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<span class="price-container <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
        <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayLabel(); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?php echo($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayValue(); ?>"
        data-price-type="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceType(); ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceWrapperCss(); ?>"
        <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="price"' : '' ?>>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
    </span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?php echo $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode()?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Price Display Settings** and change **Display Product Prices In Catalog** to **Including and Excluding Tax**. Your product prices should appear incl/exlc tax.